# Which Web Services Can I Use From .NET or Java?

Tags: 2010, web-services

I am recently starting to use SharePoint, and one question is how can other web applications retrieve data from SharePoint 2010.

Which web services can I use from either a .NET application or a Java based application?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of SOAP web services provided by SharePoint that can be used in Java and ASP.NET.  For Java, David Dudok de Wit has a good blog post about using the web services: http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-java-tutorial/.

For ASP.NET, you also have the option of using the SharePoint Client-Side Object Model.  This lets you interact with SharePoint using an object model provided by the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime assemblies.  CSOM is a bit easier to work with than the web services directly.

More info on SharePoint web services: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: We both posted the same definitive link :)

Answer (score 1):

There are many options to retrieve data from sharepoint.

1. Sharepoint server side object model.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193058(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193058%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

2  Sharepoint client side object model.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx#BasicOps_FileTasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201%28v=office.15%29.aspx#BasicOps_FileTasks)

3 Sharepoint web services and rest APIs.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142380%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The REST API is very versatile and easy to learn. Reading and writing with this interface is well documented here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: The REST API was very limited in 2010.

Comment: my bad. Didn't see 2010. I'm still asleep

Comment: Very limited = limited to ListData.svc

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of web services available in SharePoint 2010 that you can use to consume data from a SharePoint site. A quick Google search of "SharePoint 2010 Web Services" returns the following list of all available web services in SharePoint 2010:

[SharePoint 2010 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Which web service you use depends entirely upon the task that you are trying to accomplish.

Some of the most common web services used are:

[Lists Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[SiteData Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcsitedata%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

[Webs Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcwebs%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[JShare](http://www.independentsoft.de/jshare) - Java and Android API for SharePoint

[Share .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/share) - .NET Framework and Mono API for SharePoint